# Extracting alternating data from a single row into two vertical columns

Tags: excel, transpose

I have Excel data in the below format:

```
Excel column names: A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
      1st Row Data: 1    1    2    2    4    4    5    5    6    6
```

I need the following output:

```
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4 
5  5
6  6
```

How can we use the "transpose" function in this case?

Note: A, B, C, are standard Excel column headers and not user-defined columns.

Comment: Where did the 3 3 come from? Are you going from one row to two columns?  It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I m sorry Initially I had missed. 3 3. Its a Typo. You are right... I have single row, & need values in 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Populate the row below your data with the range 1:n where n is the length of the row, either by using a formula that adds 1 to the value on the cell's left or starting the sequence 1, 2, 3... and dragging right for Excel to continue it.
2. In another row, enter `=INDEX(1:1,1, 2*A2-1)` , for instance in cell A4.  Drag that formula right to extract every other value of the first row.
3. In the row below that, enter `=INDEX(1:1,1, 2*A2)` and drag it right to extract the remaining alternating values.
4. Copy and paste these two rows of data as values and transposed to end up with two vertical columns:

[image]